# C++ - Private variables in classes

Tags: c++, class, private

I am trying to create a class in seperate files with private variables.
So far my classes code is:

In TestClass.h

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_H
#define TESTCLASS_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class TestClass
{
    private:
        string hi;
    public:
        TestClass(string x);
        void set(string x);
        void print(int x);
};

#endif
```

In TestClass.cpp

```
#include "TestClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

TestClass::TestClass(string x)
{
    cout << "constuct " << x << endl;
}

void set(string x){
    hi = x;
}

void print(int x){
    if(x == 2)
        cout << hi << " x = two\n";
    else if(x < -10)
        cout << hi << " x < -10\n";
    else if(x >= 10)
        cout << hi << " x >= 10\n";
    else
        cout << hi << " x = " << x << endl;
}
```

When I try to build in Code::Blocks it says:

- ...\TestClass.cpp: In function 'void set(std::string)':
- ...\TestClass.cpp:12: error: 'hi' was not declared in this scope
- ...\TestClass.cpp: In function 'void print(int)':
- ...\TestClass.cpp:17: error: 'hi' was not declared in this scope
- ...\TestClass.cpp:19: error: 'hi' was not declared in this scope
- ...\TestClass.cpp:21: error: 'hi' was not declared in this scope
- ...\TestClass.cpp:23: error: 'hi' was not declared in this scope

But when I run it (and don't build it) everything is working.

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but `using namespace std;` in the header file is considered a bad practice as it pollutes the namespace.

Answer (score 18):

You forgot to write `TestClass::` as shown below:

```
void TestClass::set(string x)
   //^^^^^^^^^^^this

void TestClass::print(int x)
   //^^^^^^^^^^^this
```

That is necessary so that compiler can know that `set` and `print` are member functions of class `TestClass`. And once you write it, making them member functions, they can acess the private members of the class.

Also, without *TestClass::*, `set` and `print` function would become free functions.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
void TestClass::set(string x){
```

and

```
void TestClass::print(int x){
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `.cpp` file, you need to make the set and print member functions explicitly part of the class, like:

```
void TestClass::set(string x){
    hi = x;
}

void TestClass::print(int x){
    if(x == 2)
        cout << hi << " x = two\n";
    else if(x < -10)
        cout << hi << " x < -10\n";
    else if(x >= 10)
        cout << hi << " x >= 10\n";
    else
        cout << hi << " x = " << x << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't scope resolve your `print` and `set` functions with the class name.

```
void TestClass::set(string x){
    hi = x;
}

void TestClass::print(int x){
    if(x == 2)
        cout << hi << " x = two\n";
    else if(x < -10)
        cout << hi << " x < -10\n";
    else if(x >= 10)
        cout << hi << " x >= 10\n";
    else
        cout << hi << " x = " << x << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

say

```
void TestClass::set(string x){
```

instead of

```
void set(string x){
```

same for print().
You declared them as global functions instead of member functions of TestClass.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods are not defined as methods of the class. Try using TestClass::set and TestClass::print.

Answer (score -2):

```
-void set(string x) {
+void TestClass:set(string x) {
```

Comment: That's Objective-C